# How do you add custom column data to User table using Google OAuth Provider with Next-Auth?

Tags: typescript, next.js, google-oauth, next-auth

I recently found and started testing [create-t3-app](https://create.t3.gg/) as a new base for NextJS projects because it takes care of a lot of boilerplate setup for things like TypeScript, trpc, prisma, and next-auth so it'd save me a ton of time. While that's relevant, I don't think it's the source of my problem. My problem is that I use the next-auth library with the Google Provider for authentication and I'd like to track if an email is verified.

schema.prisma

```
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  email         String    @unique
  emailVerified Boolean   @default(false)
  password      String?
  role          Role      @default(USER)
  name          String?
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt
  deletedAt     DateTime?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
}
```

[...nextauth].ts

```
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      async profile(profile) {
        return {
          id: profile.sub, // I'd prefer not to have this but not supplying an id causes a TypeScript error
          email: profile.email,
          emailVerified: profile.email_verified ? true : false, // trying to turn undefined or null to true or false
          // at_hash
          name: profile.name,
          image: profile.picture
          // given_name, family_name
          // locale
        }
      }
    })
```

I get this error even though when I log profile it says email_verified is true:

```
Invalid `p.user.create()` invocation in
project/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:6:38

  3 exports.PrismaAdapter = void 0;
  4 function PrismaAdapter(p) {
  5     return {
→ 6         createUser: (data) => p.user.create({
              data: {
                email: 'dillanjwilding@gmail.com',
                emailVerified: null,
                               ~~~~
                name: 'Dillan Wilding',
                image: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp6-ViCSaOvUJMTH3hVpajCfagYI73vx1uPVDYbuTw=s96-c'
              }
            })

Argument emailVerified for data.emailVerified must not be null. Please use undefined instead.
```

I tried renaming the column from `emailVerified` to `email_verified` but it doesn't get passed through in the default definition of the `profile()` function in the Google Provider.

**The one thing that works is to make the `emailVerified` column nullable (or remove it) and User creation and authentication just doesn't use the column but authentication works. That's very limiting to not allow custom properties.**

I'd appreciate help trying to figure out how to populate the `email_verified` or `emailVerified` on the User table using next-auth's Google Provider.

Also, I'm using some of the more recent versions of things and found that some tutorials are a bit out of date. Here is my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "~1.0.5",
    "@prisma/client": "~4.9.0",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "~4.20.4",
    "@trpc/client": "~10.6.0",
    "@trpc/next": "~10.6.0",
    "@trpc/react-query": "~10.6.0",
    "@trpc/server": "~10.6.0",
    "next": "~13.1.2",
    "next-auth": "~4.19.0",
    "react": "~18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "~18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "~4.7.1",
    "react-markdown": "~8.0.4",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "~15.5.0",
    "remark-gfm": "~3.0.1",
    "superjson": "~1.12.2",
    "zod": "~3.20.2"
  },
```

**UPDATE**: I've resorted to looking at the `next-auth` package source rather than relying on the documentation. From a preliminary look, it seems like some places a boolean `email_verified` is available/used and elsewhere a date/time `emailVerified` is available/used. I'm still trying to figure out workflow, how and where I can hook into the process, and when each are available but I think this is closer to an answer.